# Sqlalchemy delete subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to delete some child rows using a filtered query without result:

```
sl = DBSession.query(Puesto.id).filter(Puesto.locales_id == id).subquery()
DBSession.query(Servicio).filter(Servicio.puestos_id.in_(sl)).delete()
```

I am getting `InvalidRequestError: Could not evaluate current criteria in Python.  Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session parameter.` as error.

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/tg2env/ceaf/ceaf/controllers/root.py", line 1673, in delete_local
    DBSession.query(Servicio).filter(Servicio.puestos_id.in_(sl)).delete()
  File "/usr/src/tg2env/lib/python2.4/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.6.6-py2.4.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2126, in delete
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
InvalidRequestError: Could not evaluate current criteria in Python.  Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session parameter.
```

I am not be able to find where the problem is...

Any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 100, accepted):

After looking in the source where your exception occurs I suggest trying this:

```
sl = DBSession.query(Puesto.id).filter(Puesto.locales_id == id).subquery()
DBSession.query(Servicio).filter(Servicio.puestos_id.in_(sl)) \
.delete(synchronize_session='fetch')
```

See the [documentation of the delete method](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete) for what this means.  Passing the `fetch` argument will basically run the query twice, once as a select and once as a delete.

If running two queries is not desired, pass `synchronize_session=False` instead and then call `session.expire_all()` immediately after the delete to [avoid having inconsistent state](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expire_all) within the `MetaData` store.

Comment: First approach works great. Why now working with synchronize_session='evaluate'?

Comment: Because the delete uses `in_` with a subquery, a `select` query is necessary for the `MetaData` to decide which of its in-memory objects to expire.  Passing this option gives it permission to do that.  Doing this unconditionally would risk poor performance in certain situations.

Comment: This doc also says if we commit immediately, we do not need to call session.expire_all(), with autocommit=False.

Comment: @Shafiul Are you sure?  I read it as, you do not need to call `expire_all` if this deletion occurs *just after* a commit, not *just before*.  If you have done other things before this deletion in the same DB transaction, there could be objects in the session that no longer have any corresponding row in the tables!

Comment: what is `DBSession` and `session` exactly ?

Comment: The `session` object essentially accumulates changes made to mapped objects and computes from that what queries need to be executed when there is a commit.  Session objects are ephemeral and created by a factory object, which by convention is called `Session` with capital S.  Session objects are meant to be short-lived, limited in scope to a single transaction, and not shared.