# SQLAlchemy delete all items and not just the first

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am trying to delete some datarecords from my db. I made cascade to also delete everything related to the datarecord. My problem is now that what if I have more than one datarecord with the same name attribute and I want to delete them all. So for example I got 3 datarecords and two have an attribute `name = Max` and the last one has the attribute `name = Peter`. How can I now delete both Max's? This is the code I got so far:

```
def delete_anw(engine):
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    f = session.query(Anwendung).filter_by(name="Max").first()
    session.delete(f)
    session.commit()
```

This code only deletes the first query that it finds. I know it's because of the `first()` but is there a method like `all()` to delete all datarecords that have the name Max?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7954618/4367 (suggests you use synchronize_session)

Comment: After trying it with synchronize_session still getting this Key (id)=(9) is still referenced from table.

Comment: Did you try the "If running two queries is not desired, pass synchronize_session=False instead and then call session.expire_all() immediately after the delete to avoid having inconsistent state within the MetaData store." part? Also if you have FK constraints, make sure they are cascading the desired behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the `.first()` method and add delete to the query itself

```
session.query(Anwendung).filter_by(name="Max").delete()
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete
Look at this for reference

Comment: Well the problem is that this doesn't work if you have relations between the tables. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think that's the case. The related objects will be affected once session.commit is issued or when session.expire_all as in the answer @Rick points out.

Comment: @Blinxen Partly correct. `Query.delete()` is a bulk operation that bypasses **in-Python cascades**, so that depends on how you've configured your relationships and foreign keys in particular; in-DB cascades will fire as usual.

Comment: @IljaEverilä just checked my relations and found out that the problem was there. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
'''
Created on 2017年10月24日

@author: leemengwei
'''

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column,Integer,String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()

class Anwendung(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tab1'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


def delete_anw():
    session = Session()
    f = session.query(Anwendung).filter_by(name="Max").delete()
    print('records deleted:',f)
    session.commit()
    session.close()

def query_anw():
    session = Session()
    f = session.query(Anwendung).filter_by(name="Max").all()
    print('records matched:',len(f))
    session.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/test",echo=True)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    query_anw()
    delete_anw()
    query_anw()
```

The code above works fine for me.The records are found and deleted.

Comment: You can't post some code like this. please try to explain what you are trying to do and what are problem you are facing.

Comment: sorry.since Blinxen said "This is the code I got so far",so I write a complete example that explains how to delete more than one record by sqlAlchemy.

Comment: sorry.since Mr. Blinxen said "This is the code I got so far",so I write a complete example that explains how to delete more than one record by sqlAlchemy.use query before and after delete,to show that the records are sucessfully deleted.I hope this will be helpful,so the others can use the code directly and without the need to search documents.