# How to delete all users with specified role

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

These are my User and Role models:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, server_default='')
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, server_default='')
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    answers = db.relationship('Answer', backref="examinee", lazy=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    active = db.Column('is_active', db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='0')
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='user_roles', backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

class UserRoles(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    UniqueConstraint('user_id', 'role_id', name='user_role_uniqueness')
```

How can I remove all users with specific role such as 'student'?

I have tried the following snippet which did not work:

```
@app.route('/removeAllStudentUsers', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def remove_all_student_users():
    default_role_name = "student"
    default_role = Role.query.filter(Role.name == default_role_name).first()
    User.query.filter().delete(and_(User.roles.contains(default_role), func.count(User.roles) == 1)) # this line causes the error
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('users'))
```

The above code causes this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Valid strategies for session synchronization are 'evaluate', 'fetch', False

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7954618/11647025

Comment: dear @crissal No, when I use this: `sq = session.query(Role).filter(Role.name == "student").subquery()` and `session.query(User.roles).filter(User.roles.in_(sq)).delete(synchronize_session='fetch')` I get this error: `AttributeError: 'SecureCookieSession' object has no attribute 'query'`

Comment: Try it with `db.session` instead of  `session`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your attempt to achieve that, including the fact that you might need a group by in order to check the count of the roles.

I would implement this a following:

```
_ = (
    User.query
    .filter(User.roles.any(Role.name == default_role_name))   # 1
    .filter(~User.roles.any(Role.name != default_role_name))  # 2
    .delete(synchronize_session=False)  # 3
)
```

where:

1. makes sure to return only those `User` who has the given role
2. makes sure to exclude the `User` who has also other roles (this is what you try to solve with `func.count`)
3. this is the solution for the error you get.